# Primary Key in QtableWidget - If row exists update otherwise Add

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Being new to Qt. I wanted to know if there was a way to add a primary key in a `QtableWidget`.The reason I want to do this is because I want to create a mechanism so that if I add a row with a key that is not in the table it gets added as a new row otherwise the existing row with that key gets updated.Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Assuming m_table of QTableWidget* type
        // Assuming single column

        const int rowCount = m_table->rowCount();
        if(rowToInsert < rowCount)
        { 
           m_table->setItem(rowToInsert, 0, /* your data */ );
        }
        else
        {
          m_table->setRowCount(rowCount + 1);
          m_table->setItem(rowCount + 1, 0, /* your data */ );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `QTableWidgetItem::setData ( int role, const QVariant & value )` method to set your data (primary key) with custom `role`, and `QVariant QTableWidgetItem::data ( int role )` to retreive it. `role` should be `Qt::UserRole` or any number higher than `32`. See reference for [QTableWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant & value)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) for more info.
And if you're new to Qt, you should look for [Qt model/view](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html), in your case it can be smart to do your check in `model` and display model's data in `QTableView` instead of `QTableWidget`.